# mount and sync non english folder & file names

Tags: samba, mount, directory, utf-8, unicode

I'm trying to rsync a folder who's name contains non-english characters it breaks the whole rsync, how can I copy a folder even if they don't have english characters in it?

Answer (score 1):

Well I live on a non-english country and have no problems with accents and other symbols. What I suggest is normalizing all machines to use UTF-8 and maybe check the encoding on those filenames.